# Append a string and $index in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In My AngularJs app, I have an ng-repeat like:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="pl in parentlist">
  <div id="test{{$index}}" ng-model='list{{$index}}' >Test</div>
</div>
```

The Id in the Div gets appends and renders like expected `id="test0"` but the ng-model doesn't behave in the same way and it throws an error

> [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '$index' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 8 of the expression [list{{$index}}] starting at [$index}}]

How do I achieve this appending? use filters?

Comment: what is the point of this, you have already array in your hand why do you need these primitive models?

Comment: I need to dynamically add a div everytime a object is added to the "parentlist". lets say $scope.parentlist.test1=[]; test1 gets added to $scope.parentlist, I want a div to add dynamically with the ng-model="test1".

Comment: so you need to key of parentlist object am I right?

Comment: @wickY26 - Thanks,Got what you are trying to say. fixed it.

Comment: I tried to create an exmaple for you check my answer if it fits you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need bind your div with the `keys` of your `parentlist` just change your ng-repeat to this,

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in parentlist">
   <div id="{{key}}" ng-model="key">{{key}}</div>
</div>
```

here is working [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/bAIkqrPEqXT7O0yS8lNh?p=preview)...

Answer (score 0):

Make `list` an array. Instead of having individual `list` variables, you have one array with multiple values

The HTML then becomes

`<div id="test{{$index}}" ng-model='list[$index]' >Test</div>`

Comment: This renders as is like ng-model="list[$index]"

Answer (score 0):

If you need to append the index to a string (where you currently are on the ng-repeat loop iteration) you can do it like this:

```
<div id="num_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="obj in someArray">
    num_{{$index}}
</div>
```

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/ba6EM0KShiZ8AS8uKVCm